# Update Column Of All Rows In A Table From Another Table Using Primary Key And Foreign Key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query to update all rows in a column with using of primary and foreign key relationship but the error is:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression. The statement has been terminated.

My query is:

```
Update T_OP
    Set DOCID = (Select DocID from T_Reg_Patients)
where Fk_RegID = (Select Pk_RegID from T_Reg_Patients)
```

`Table1`:

```
Pk_RegID    Name    DocID
1           Sam      1
2           Sam2     2
3           Sam3     3
4           Sam4     4
```

`Table 2`:

```
Pk_OPID   Fk_RegID   Name   DOCID
1         1          Sam    NULL
2         2          Sam2   NULL
3         3          Sam3   NULL
4         4          Sam4   NULL
```

I have to update the DOCID from the table 1  if the Fk_RegId(In Table 2) is same as Pk_RegID(In Table 1)...

Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: You say table1 and table2, but the query has T_OP and Reg_Patients... Stick to same name! Also show us the expected table data after the update.

Comment: Thank u for ur messege join is worked for me ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below query.

```
 UPDATE t
 SET t.DOCID=p.DOCID
 FROM T_OP t
   JOIN T_Reg_Patients p ON p.Pk_RegID=t.Fk_RegID
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `JOIN` instead:

```
Update T_OP
    Set docid = rp.DocID
    from t_op o JOIN
         T_Reg_Patients rp
         on o.Fk_RegID = rp.Pk_RegID;
```

However, there is probably no need to store `DocID` in both tables.  Why not just use a `JOIN` when you need to fetch the value?

Answer (score 0):

```
Update t2
 set t2.docid=t1.DocID 
from
T_Reg_Patients t1 join t_op t2 on
t2.Fk_RegID=t1.Pk_RegID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table
 SET t.DOCID=p.DOCID
 FROM T_OP t
   JOIN T_Reg_Patients p ON p.Pk_RegID=t.Fk_RegID
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql you can use -

```
Update table2 t2 join table1 t1
on t2.Fk_RegID = t1.Pk_RegID
set t2.DOCID = t1.DocID;
```